# Creating Incoming Webhook URL With BOT Email

Tags: gitlab, webex

I am trying to integrate gitlab with webex_teams. When I create webhook url using incoming webhooks app, notification profile showing my cisco account email. Instead of that I created a bot for this notifications. But not sure how to create incoming webhook url using bot email. One of my colleague created jira webhook url with jira notifcation bot. he left the company. now I have no one to help me to get this done.

Please help me how to create a webex teams incoming webhook url with bot email.

I am trying to integrate gitlab with webex_teams. When I create webhook url using incoming webhooks app, notification profile showing my cisco account email. Instead of that I created a bot for this notifications. But not sure how to create incoming webhook url using bot email. One of my colleague created jira webhook url with jira notifcation bot. he left the company. now I have no one to help me to get this done.

Please help me how to create a webex teams incoming webhook url with bot email.